# “no root device specified. Boot arguments must include a root= parameter” after installing rEFInd on windows 10 / pop os dual boot

Tags: ubuntu, dual-boot, uefi, initramfs, refind

I recently set up dual boot on a new dell xps 9700, carving off two partitions (/boot and root) for Pop OS (ubuntu-derivative). This was working fine, except Pop OS was taking boots without giving me an option for windows, and I wanted a more sleek boot experience, so I installed rEFInd using the following methodology:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:rodsmith/refind
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install refind
```

Now I get the rEFInd boot selection screen, and can select and boot into windows just fine. But trying to boot into pop os drops me into initramfs with the message "no root device specified. Boot arguments must include a root= parameter". Sadly I'm out of my depth here, but it seems like there must be a way to point it in the right direction for boot. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I feel a bit dumb, but I have an answer to my own question. rEFInd shows all partitions it can find by default, and I was selecting the Pop OS /boot partition, rather than the root partition.

Posting this follow-up in the hope that it may help someone else in the future.